# Selecting after certain elements with the same classes

Tags: html, css

I've ran into a weird problem that I don't understand. I want to select the 3rd and after of elements that have the `.select` class. I thought this would be as simple as using `.select:nth-child(n+3)`, but in my example I am selecting the 3rd and after element with the .box class.

Why is this not filtering out the DIVs that don't have the `.select` class on it? The same result happens with

```
.select:nth-of-type(n+3)
```

```css
.box {
      background: #000;
      margin-bottom: 6px;
      height: 20px;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    
    .select:nth-child(n+3) {
      background: red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="box">.box</div>
    <div class="box">.box</div>
    <div class="box">.box</div>
    <div class="box select">.box .select</div>
    <div class="box select">.box .select</div>
    <div class="box select">.box .select</div>
```

Comment: simply because nth-child is first applying to work with ALL the childs then come the class to add more restriction

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. I noticed the answer you linked is about 7 years old, is there any update/selector that can handle this request now?

Comment: The intial answer is 7 years old, but the last edit is recent ;) ... And nth-child/nth-of-type still work the same, you may only find workaround if you want, but no generic selector